# Architechture and Platform relationship?

Tags: architecture, netbeans-platform

I would like to know, after your permission, precisely, the definition and  the relationship  between the architecture and the platform, in  programming language

Comment: What exactly do you mean by platform? And how is this related to a programming language?

Comment: what are the platforms in the programming language???

Comment: There are no platforms ***in*** a programming ***language***. Maybe the question refers to something like the .NET platform or the Java Runtime Environment. But these are not part of a language. They just provide an environment in which a program is executed.